# Disk Usage info

Tags: go, archlinux

I first wrote a sh-bash ([Disk Info sh-script](https://gist.github.com/19286d19b906a98030cfa838d5ae0187)) script, and now a similar script in Go. The Go program shows mounted from server directories wrong by me.

I using:

Kernel: 5.3.11-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.2.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 tk: Gtk 3.24.12 
           info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Manjaro Linux

Here is the Go program:

```
//pacman -S go
//go get -u golang.org/x/sys/unix

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    syscall "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

type DiskStatus struct {
    All   uint64 `json:"all"`
    Used  uint64 `json:"used"`
    Free  uint64 `json:"free"`
    Avail uint64 `json:"avail"`
}

// disk usage of path/disk
func DiskUsage(path string) (disk DiskStatus) {
    fs := syscall.Statfs_t{}
    err := syscall.Statfs(path, &fs)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    disk.All = fs.Blocks * uint64(fs.Bsize)
    disk.Avail = fs.Bavail * uint64(fs.Bsize)
    disk.Free = fs.Bfree * uint64(fs.Bsize)
    disk.Used = disk.All - disk.Free
    return
}

const (
    B  = 1
    KB = 1024 * B
    MB = 1024 * KB
    GB = 1024 * MB
)

func main() {
    path := "/"
    funcName("/mnt/ix4")
    funcName("/mnt/ix4300d")
    funcName(path)
    //funcName("192.168.178.42/share")
}

func funcName(path string) {
    disk := DiskUsage(path)
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println(path, ":")
    fmt.Printf("All: %.2f GB\n", float64(disk.All)/float64(GB))
    fmt.Printf("Avail: %.2f GB\n", float64(disk.Avail)/float64(GB))
    fmt.Printf("Used: %.2f GB\n", float64(disk.Used)/float64(GB))
}
```

the correct values for /mnt/ix4300d
are

```
5216716992 = blocks_avail
5216 GB free
9%used 192.168.178.42:/share
```

the Golang version gives me for /mnt/ix4300d
are

```
/mnt/ix4300d :
All: 862.34 GB
Avail: 180.74 GB
Used: 637.73 GB
```

Go gives the same values ​​as my system partition ("/").

Comment: Are you sure `syscall.Statfs(path, &fs)` does not return you an error?

Comment: @zerkms error never happens to me. (same with explicit error https://gist.github.com/8c16fbcb2a96888966c20b4490ceb2ca )

Comment: Good, it was just a general recommendation to not write code that ignores errors.

Comment: On my machine that working good: /boot/efi :
All: 0.50 GB
Avail: 0.49 GB
Used: 0.01 GB

/ :
All: 467.02 GB
Avail: 305.26 GB
Used: 137.97 GB

Comment: @MaximPanfilov here its mounted via `mount -t nfs afp://ix4-300d.local:share /mnt/ix4300d`. its an old NAS (ix4-200d)

Comment: It might be a bug in xfce (https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16202)